# neo4j bolt connect stuck

Tags: java, neo4j

I connect neo4j-community-3.1.1 via neo4j-java-driver to a non-local server like this:

```java
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://10.209.20.211:7687",
                AuthTokens.basic("username", "xxxx"));
System.out.println("neo4j driver created..");
Session session = driver.session();
System.out.println("session opened..");
```

but it never reaches "System.out.println("session opened..");"
obviously, it is stuck on "driver.session();"

I'm sure that the network is working, having tested it via `telnet 10.209.20.211 7687`.

And the neo4j.conf file like this:

```
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
```

Now, what's the problem?

Comment: it's weird, I have never seen such a prob, and it should work. Have you try it locally ? Can you try to connect to your distant server with a local 'cypher-shell' client

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem this way:

```
Config cfg = Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig();
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://10.209.20.211:7687",
        AuthTokens.basic("username", "xxxx"), cfg);
System.out.println("neo4j driver created..");
Session session = driver.session();
System.out.println("session opened..");
```